# Issue binding click event in jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to bind a click event to .ui-state-default after a jQuery datepicker has been rendered (I don't have any control over the html that's creating the datepicker so I can't use any datepicker specific events) and it works fine using $.bind() but not with $.on().

$.bind() that works in console:

```
$('[data-handler=selectDay] a.ui-state-default').bind('click', function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active')) return;
        alert('changed date');
        $("button.checkout").addClass('disabled');
        $("button.checkout span").html('Choose Your Payment Method');
        $(".stage3").html(tmpl('stage3_tpl')).removeClass('noBg');
});
```

$.on() that doesn't work on the page:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '[data-handler=selectDay] a.ui-state-default', function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active')) return;
        alert('changed date');
        $("button.checkout").addClass('disabled');
        $("button.checkout span").html('Choose Your Payment Method');
        $(".stage3").html(tmpl('stage3_tpl')).removeClass('noBg');
});
```

The datepicker is not always on the page so I don't believe I can use $.bind()?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: would you mind to provide the datepicker initialization code, or where/when you do it? I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't see why it wouldn't work, perhaps try attaching using `$('[data-handler=selectDay] a.ui-state-default').on('click',...`

Comment: What is the version of `jquery`? what do you mean by *"works in console"*..? What do you mean by *"doesn't work"*..?

Comment: console as in running it in Chrome's console.  "doesn't work" as in the console.log() doesn't execute and neither does the rest of the code.  Currently using jQuery 1.8.1.

Comment: Is this a `jquery-ui` datepicker or some other plugin? Are you able to provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something related to `DOM` changes. The `jQuery.on()` method is bound to existent `DOM` elements, that is why it is not working for dynamically added date picker elements.

> jQuery Documentation: **Event handlers are bound only to the
>   currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time
>   your code makes the call to .on()**

`jQuery.bind()` work as well for existent elements. So it will work for the first one attached to a `DOM` but not for the rest of them dynamically attached.

The solution for this is using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which listen for `DOM` changes and allows you to react accordingly. There is a nice `jQuery` plugin called '[Live Query](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery)' which simplifies the process of creating Mutation Observers for specific elements within your `DOM`.

For instance, your code using `jQuery.livequery()` would look like this:

```
$('body').livequery(
    'table td[data-handler=selectDay] a.ui-state-default',
    function(elem){
        if( jQuery(elem).hasClass('ui-state-active') ) return;
        jQuery(elem).on('click', function(){
            $("button.checkout").attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('disabled');
            $("button.checkout span").html('Choose Your Payment Method');
        });
    }
);
```

It will listen to `DOM` changes in `<body> <table> <td data-handler="selectDay"] <a class="ui-state-default">` then act accordingly on clicking an element.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/ej96f7m5/

```js
/**
 * Livequery listen for DOM mutation events
 * this allows to keep listening date picker
 * events, even after being dynamically appended to
 * DOM
 */
$('body').livequery(
    'table td[data-handler=selectDay] a.ui-state-default',
    function(elem){
        if( jQuery(elem).hasClass('ui-state-active') ) return;
        jQuery(elem).on('click', function(){
            $("button.checkout").attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('disabled');
            $("button.checkout span").html('Choose Your Payment Method');
        });
    }
);
$('.clean').on('click', function(){
    /** 
     * Reset testing playground
     * This simulates dynamic DOM Mutation
     */
    jQuery('.wrap').empty();
    jQuery('.wrap').append('<input type="text" class="date-picker"/>');
    jQuery('button.checkout').attr('disabled',false);
    jQuery('button.checkout span').html('Checkout');
    $(function() {
        $( ".date-picker" ).datepicker();
    });
});
// Run datepicker
$(function() {    
    $( ".date-picker" ).datepicker();
});
```

```css
.wrap {
    border: 1px solid #fefefe;
    background: #fafafa;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrap input {
    border: 1px solid #fcfcfc;
    padding: .5em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
.buttons {
    text-align: center;
    background: #fbfbfb;
}
.checkout {
    background: #ee5555;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
}
button:disabled {
    background: #efefef;
    color: #999;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://staticelite.info/elitenetwork/scripts/jquery.livequery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <input type="text" class="date-picker"/>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="clean">Clean</button> | 
    <button class="checkout"><span>Checkout</span></button>
</div>
```

P.S: Clicking on *Clean* will simulate an element dynamically attached to DOM.

Comment: I'm Sorry @José SAYAGO but that's not true. **you can attach handlers using the `on()` to dynamically created elements** - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7mbsrhz/). People mistakes is to attach to the target element selector: `$('.class').on('click',function...` that will not work because the element does not exist. you need to attach it to something that does: `$(document).on('click','.class', function...` this way the document is being watched and every time an element that has the class name will be attached to that handler.

Comment: The problem here is the plugin itself - that is returning false every time the `selectDay` event is fired, deleting the `return false;` solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry pal, but you are the one getting it wrong. If you test your own snippet, it stops working once you dynamically attach elements to the DOM (I tested it on your own example, check it out http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/a9sysooh/). That's why I posted this solution, your suggestion of hacking jQuery UI doesn't work because jQuery is unable to keep listening once an element has been detached from DOM and reinserted again.

Comment: What is not working??? its working great... I suggest you try again - And ofcurse jQuery can - the `on` will reattach the click event every time a new element will be created that has the correct selector. since jQuery 1.7 `on()` replaced `live()` and thats exactly why its there - thats a fact. (reminder: [**PROOF**](http://jsfiddle.net/g7mbsrhz/) )

Comment: And From jQuery: When a **selector is provided**, the event handler is referred to as delegated. **The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector**. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) **and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector**.

Answer (score 3):

Easy one!

*Datepicker (jQuery-UI)*:

- When you select a date (click event added to the `td` that holds the `a.ui-state-default` it fires a method called `_selectDay`.
- The datepicker plugin attach the methods using an attach method called `_attachHandlers` that attaches `_selctDay` to the elements who has the attribute `data-handler=selectDay` and adds a `return false` after it to prevent defaults and propagation (same as `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation();`).

So the problem is that `return false` added in the `_attachHandlers` method of the plugin.
I removed it and saved it to git for you ( the entire jQuery-UI with all) but you can also remove it yourself by searching the method and deleting the `return false` after the `selectDay` attachment.

**Demo** (external resources - includes the custom jQuery UI): [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/3zvh9uot/)

**GitHub** - custom jQuery-UI without the return false: [**GitHub**](https://github.com/shlomohass/jQuery.ui.without.handlers.limit/blob/09302b3c0b55bcfbff50375acce578c91b461243/jQueryUi-datepicker-custom.clicks.1.js)

Code Tested:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '[data-handler=selectDay] a.ui-state-default', function(){
    //This will be triggered after the handler of the jQuery UI: 
    if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active')) return false;
    alert('changed date');
    /* Rest of your code */
    return false;
});

$(function() {    
    $( ".date-picker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: I could not get this solution to work, firstly because my version of jQuery UI is older than the example you give, but even after using the full version from GitHub that you provided, I was still not getting the alert() coming through.

Answer (score 2):

Use "**bind change Event**" instead "**bind click Event**"

example:

```
    $('[data-handler=selectDay] a.ui-state-default').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", 
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true, 
        yearRange: '-50:c', 
        maxDate: new Date,          
        showOn: "both", 
        buttonImage: "../../calender-icon.png", 
        buttonImageOnly: true, 
        beforeShow:   
        BeforeShowForDatePicker, 
        onClose: onCloseForDatePicker }).bind("change", function () {});
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use the built in events. For example:

```
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert('changed date');
            $("button.checkout").addClass('disabled');
            $("button.checkout span").html('Choose Your Payment Method');
            $(".stage3").html(tmpl('stage3_tpl')).removeClass('noBg');
        }
    });
```

For more information take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect).

Worth noting that the things that I would consider events such as onSelect and onClose are listed in the options list and NOT the events list.

Comment: Can you bind multiple onSelect functions to the datepicker?  I can't add to or override the existing function unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the page is ready first with:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```

If i am correct. This solved the problem the last time for me. Don't know if you do that?

Comment: Yep, it's wrapped in $(function(){ });

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is incorrect, you can bind event listeners to elements that are not in the DOM yet using event delegation. As others stated the real issue is jQuery UI killing the click event bubbling so just bind your handler to the mouseup event instead:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', 'a.ui-state-default', function() {
  // Stuff
});
```